# c++ sprintf function and fstream to create/check a text file

Tags: c++, fstream, printf

I am having some trouble with sprintf and fstream functions in order to create new text files for a POS program/check whether the file already exists. I don't know if i am doing something wrong because the same set of functions works fine in other places in my code...

This particular section of code is taking input from the user to create a details file, the name is made up of the first and last name details that were entered into the system. For some reason the new file is not being created. When I step through the program I can see that the custDetC variable is being filled with the correct data. I have also included the file existence check as it may or may not have something to do with the issue at hand...

Tony Mickel

```
    sprintf(custDetC,"%s%s.txt", firstName.c_str(), lastName.c_str());
    cout << custDetC << endl;

    FileEX = FileExists(custDetC);

    if (FileEX == true)
    {
        fopen_s(&custDetF,custDetC, "rt");

        fprintf(custDetF, "%s %s\n", firstName, lastName);
        fprintf(custDetF, "$d\n", phoneNo);
        fprintf(custDetF, "%s $s\n", unitHouseNum, street);
        fprintf(custDetF, "%s %s %d", suburb, state, postCode);

        fclose(custDetF);
    }
    else
    {
        char *buf = new char[100];
        GetCurrentPath(buf);
        cout << "file " << custDetC << " does not exist in " << buf << endl;
    }
}

bool FileExists(char* strFilename) 
{
    bool flag = false;
    std::fstream fin;
    // _MAX_PATH is the maximum length allowed for a path
    char CurrentPath[_MAX_PATH];
    // use the function to get the path
    GetCurrentPath(CurrentPath);
    fin.open(strFilename, ios::in);

    if( fin.is_open() )
    {
        //cout << "file exists in " << CurrentPath << endl;
        flag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //cout << "file does not exist in " << CurrentPath << endl;
        flag = false;
    }
    fin.close();

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Also, **snprintf**! _Use it!_ Never use sprintf; that's where many buffer overruns come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be opening the file for reading, but you need to open it for writing.

Instead of `"rt"` use `"wt"` in `fopen_s()`

Comment: that seems to create the file, but i get a nice Unhandled exception error of:
Unhandled exception at 0x0f9d13af (msvcr100d.dll) in POS_test2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x656e616a

Comment: which was indeed me not thinking about what i was writing to the file and sending a full size string into a single char... e.g. adding .c_str() to the end of the string variables